# Delete button not work bootstrap modal and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, destroy

I created one table that list items, and I added two buttons(edit and delete) so, the button edit is working, but the button delete is not working, and I'm making me carzy because I don't find the error. this is the table:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table align-items-center table-flush">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>text</th>
            <th class="disabled-sorting" width="10%"></th>
            <th class="disabled-sorting" width="10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($Items as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $item->text }}</td>
                <td><a href="{{ route('ItemsController.edit', $item->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-fab btn-icon btn-round" title="Edit">
                        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-fab btn-icon btn-round btn-delete" title="Delete" data-id="{{ $item->id }}" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#modal-default" data-route="{{ route('ItemsController.destroy', $item->id) }}" data-title="{{ $item->id }}">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

the modal is:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-default" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-default" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Item</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Delete?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <form class="" action="" method="post">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="button">yes, delete</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript data:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', function(){
        $('.modal form').attr('action', $(this).data('route'));
        $('#ModalLabel').text($(this).data('title'));
    })
</script>
```

and controller function destroy

```
public function destroy(Items $item) {
    $item->delete();

    return redirect()->route('items.index')->with('success', 'Deleted Success');
}
```

I checked it line by line, and I don't know what I'm wrong, please help me

Many times thanks for getting into this.

Comment: where you send the XHR Request?

Comment: You're not passing any data in through your delete modal. The only thing in your form is the method and the CSRF token. The only things your javascript is updating on the click method is the action attribute and the label text.

Comment: ahmmmm... I can pass it with this: data-post-id={{ $item->id }     ???

Comment: `data-post-id={{ $item->id }}` only adds it to the a href that the modal is toggling off of. But you're not doing anything with it from there. That value is not going to automatically jump into your form.

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger your modal from JS.

If it is bootstrap 4 then just simply open it using,

```
$('.modal form').attr('action', $(this).data('route'));
$('#ModalLabel').text($(this).data('title'));

//This will trigger modal
$("#modal-default").modal();
```

If it is bootstrap 5 then just simply open it using,

```
$('.modal form').attr('action', $(this).data('route'));
$('#ModalLabel').text($(this).data('title'));

//This will trigger modal
modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById("modal-default"));
modal.show();
```